LWC launch Omni Channel Email & Phone utility bar actions
How can I launch the Omni Channel Email & Phone utility bar actions?
I have checked the lightning/platformUtilityBarApi and lightning/navigation, but I couldn't figure out how I can launch the Omni channel utility bar actions for Email & Phone.
Please let me know if its feasible to invoke the standard Omni-channel actions like Email & Phone from LWC.
E.g. Email action from omni-channel utility bar.

